# How to ignore all changes files in wwwroot/js directory in .gitignore

Tags: git, asp.net-core

as the title says. How do I ignore all files in wwwroot/js directory for my ASP.NET Core Application. I'm using TypeScript that automatically create js files in my wwwroot/js directory, so I don't want .js in my changes.

What I Already try in my .gitignore files.

```
wwwroot/js/
**/wwwroot/js
wwwroot/js/*
**/wwwroot/js/*
/SolutionFolder/WebFolder/wwwroot/js/*
```

And none of them is working.

Here's my project path:

```
Project
   SolutionFolder
      WebFolder
         wwwroot
            js
      Project.sln
   .gitattributes
   .gitignore
```

Any solution? Thank you before.

Comment: do you want git to ignore all file in this folder `wwwroot/js/`?

Comment: yes, all files in that folder.

Comment: have you tried adding just this `wwwroot/js/` ? What happens ? Are they still showing up in `git status `?

Comment: Also where is this `.gitignore` file located?

Comment: yes, i already just add them one by one. and nothing works. outside my solution folder

Comment: and also i already tried inserting all the directory. like this `/SolutionFolder/WebFolder/wwwroot/js/*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184188/discussion-between-vishnu-narayanan-and-james).

Comment: nvm, i just need to delete all files in `wwwroot/js` and problem solve. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Geno Chen said, what do you mean by "none of them is working"? Have you tried to delete all files in from `wwwroot/js`? After that just commit the changes and try to rebuild the Solution again. and your all deleted files in `wwwroot/js` is back without including them in the changes again.

Also `SolutionFolder/WebFolder/wwwroot/js/*` is already correct. try just using this one in your `.gitignore`

Comment: This can prevent those files from tracking by Git in the future, but they are still remain in the Git history... Then it's time to ask what the author's attitude to the history is :-)

Comment: And, notice that the original question uses `/SolutionFolder/...` instead of `SolutionFolder/...`, so the last line of `.gitignore` may not hit the requested path if this folder is not under root directory.

Answer (score 1):

In the .csproj file, inside the tag `<PropertyGroup> </PropertyGroup>` add `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>`

**Example**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then, delete all files from **wwwroot/js** and add that path in the **.gitignore**

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "none of them is working"? I f you mean you are still seeing it in git tracking or so, you may need `git filter-branch` for deleting the directory from the git history.

Also, the correct path in `.gitignore` is `SolutionFolder/WebFolder/wwwroot/js/*`. However you have already use glob `**` to cover it.